# Get the Pandas groupby agg output columns

Tags: pandas

Here is my code

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
 
df['country'] = ['UK', 'UK', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA']
df['name'] = ['United Kingdom', 'United Kingdom', 'United States', 'United States', 'United States']
df['year'] = [1, 2, 1, 2, 3]
df['x'] = [100, 125, 200, 225, 250]

print(df.groupby(['country', 'name']).agg({'x':['mean', 'count']}))
```

The output I get is

```
 x      
                         mean count
country name                       
UK      United Kingdom  112.5     2
USA     United States   225.0     3
```

But I need a result as a list of rows

```
[['UK','United Kingdom',112.5,2],...]
```

or columns

```
[['UK', 'USA'],['United Kingdom','United States'],[112.5,225],[2,3]]
```

The name column can consist of an arbitrary number of words, e.g. Kingdom of the Netherlands.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Convert `MultiIndex` to columns by `as_index=False` parameter, then convert `DataFrame` to numpy array and last to list:

```
print(df.groupby(['country', 'name'], as_index=False).agg({'x':['mean', 'count']}).to_numpy().tolist())
[['UK', 'United Kingdom', 112.5, 2], ['USA', 'United States', 225.0, 3]]
```

For second output add transposing:

```
print(df.groupby(['country', 'name'], as_index=False).agg({'x':['mean', 'count']}).T.to_numpy().tolist())
[['UK', 'USA'], ['United Kingdom', 'United States'], [112.5, 225.0], [2, 3]]
```